# Python Newbie trying to generate 1000th prime

Tags: encoding

```
z=1
counter=0
itersLeft=z
while (counter<1001):
    while(itersLeft>0):
        if (z%itersLeft==0):
            if (z/itersLeft==1):
                counter=counter+1
                z=z+1
        itersLeft=itersLeft-1
    z=z+1
print z
```

This will not return any values. Just static, no syntax error. Any help on how to modify this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a logic error.

The first time through your loop, `counter` goes up to 1, and `itersLeft` goes down to 0. After that you never enter the inner loop again because your loop condition, `itersLeft > 0`, is always False.